# HP/3com 9552 802.11n AP won't let some clients connect

Tags: networking, wifi, access-point, 3com, 802.1

I splurged and bought an HP/3com 9552 802.11a/b/g/n access point. Like most enterprise-grade access points, it has very fine-grained configuration options.

I'm pretty sure I've configured it correctly for WPA/WPA2 with CCMP/TKIP encryption using a PSK. All my laptops and smartphones can connect effortlessly to the AP using 802.11g, n on 2.4 GHz, and n on 5 GHz. But my Roku XDS box cannot connect at all. The AP reports a "port security violation" when an attempt is made.

Since most other devices can connect without problem, I suspect the issue is with the Roku. But perhaps there is some setting on the AP that I can tweak to get it to work.

I have no other special configuration on the AP.

Can someone point me in the right direction to debug and correct the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a case of the Roku's implementation of WPA/WPA2. You might check directly with Roku for definitive assistance/information.

Comment: You'd think all this stuff was pretty standard by now. WPA2 has been around a while.

Comment: Not all devices are manufactured in the same year with the same components or necessarily even similar software. It's the age of "just-in-time-manufacturing" meets "open (to interpretation too) standards..."